# Trace.Writeline() not working in Provider Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, azure, logging

I have a created a SharePoint Provider Hosted Add-In and deployed the code on Azure. Trace.Writeline() doesnt seem to be working as I cant see anything in .../azurewebsite/trace.axd

I am able to see logs when I deployed a normal ASP.NET MVC application on Azure on .../azurewebsite/trace.axd but unable to find logs when Proivder Hsoted Add-In is deployed to Azure and .app is installed on SharePoint Online

**EDIT:**
Able to get trace and error messages in Controllers of ASP.NET MVC application as suggested by below answers but unable to get trace and error messages in **/Services/RemoteEventReceiver.svc.cs** file.

Comment: Implemented the PnP sample and its working. https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Debug.Tracing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the system.web section of your web.config file:

```
<trace enabled="true" localOnly="false" requestLimit="100" />
```

Or enable it as below via code:

```
public static void EnableTracing()
        {
            Configuration configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            TraceSection section = (TraceSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/trace");
            section.Enabled = true;
            section.LocalOnly = false;
            configuration.Save();
        }
```

After that to view trace logs, go to `pages/trace.axd`.

Do check out the excellent PnP code sample for this on how to trace and debug provider hosted app.

[Debug and Trace Provider hosted app](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Debug.Tracing)

Comment: Working on Controller files but not in /Services/RemoteEventReceiver.svc.cs file.

Answer (score 3):

Few points to check:

1. In `web.config` add

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
     <trace>
       <listeners>
         <add name="WebPageTraceListener"
             type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener,
             System.Web,
             Version=4.0.0.0,
             Culture=neutral,
             PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
       </listeners>
     </trace>
   </system.diagnostics>
```

2. In `web.config` add (for remote `localOnly="false"`):

```xml
<trace enabled="true" localOnly="false" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" mostRecent="true" pageOutput="false" />
```

3. In Azure portal, under your web app -> Monitoring -> Diagnostic logs, make sure application logging is enabled and level is `Verbose` (**note** this settings are disabled automatically in 12 hours):
   [image]
4. Deploy your app and in Azure click Your web app -> Monitoring -> Log Stream. You should trace events from your app.  You can also configure it to show traces right inside Visual Studio (in Server Explorer, right-click your web app and select View Streaming Logs.).

Must read article - [Troubleshoot a web app in Azure App Service using Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio)